# How to use the EMG Raw Data in Myo Armband

Tags: myo

I'm working on a project to try to recognize some movements/poses for use in rehabilitation therapy using [Myo Gesture Control Armband](https://www.myo.com/).

I have three questions:

1. Which is the maximum and minimum value that `EMG Raw Data` returns?
2. How do you interpret the `EMG Raw Data`?
3. The minimum value returned by the `EMG Raw Data` is for a relaxed muscle and the maximum value is a fully contracted muscle?

PS1: [Question in Myo Developer Forum](https://developer.thalmic.com/forums/topic/2839/)

PS2.: The most important to me is learn how interpret the `EMG Raw Data`. With some didactic sample. I want to create my own gestures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is from my looking results and understanding:

1. EMG Raw Data return value from -128 to 127 (8-bit value).
2. We don't really know what is EMG Raw Data. We can't say it's mV directly from muscles intensity. Sensors measure mV and convert to 8-bit data.
3. This is signal. Around 0 is "relaxed muscle" not minimum. But converting from mV to 8-bit data can make strange values too. Soo 2. and 3. question I can't really answer how it's work, because Myo don't show own hardware for converting values (or I don't find that). 
   I recommend visit [Myo diagnostic page](http://diagnostics.myo.com/) and see what happend in EMG graphs while you relaxed and contracted muscle.

Comment: @bibliolytic Not really know. [Here](https://github.com/thalmiclabs/myo.js/blob/master/docs.md) I see what is data, but I don't see how they change volts to 8-bit presentation. I know they violate the Nyquist theorem with this range.

Comment: Ah sorry, I just realized I was thinking of different hardware...I will delete my comment

Comment: I visit the Myo diagnostics page as you suggested but what does the EMG graphs represent? X axis is time, but what about the Y axis

Comment: @JorgeJiménez Y axis is EMG Raw data (some kind of intensity). Like I write in this answer.